# Converter odt para pdf

Tags: c#, libreoffice

Preciso converter arquivos da extensão do .*ODT* para .*PDF*, se eu rodar o seguinte comando no cmd ele funciona:

```
cd C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program>
soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir C:\temp\ C:\temp\a.odt
```

Contudo converti ele para *c#* e não funciona, alguém sabe o que está errado?

```
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\temp\a.odt");
        string fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\temp");
        //soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir C:\temp\ C:\temp\a.odt
        var pdfProcess = new Process();
        pdfProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe";
        pdfProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =
            String.Format("--headless --convert-to pdf --outdir C:\temp C:\temp\a.odt"
                                  , fileName);
        //  pdfProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = fileDir;
        //pdfProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //pdfProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        //pdfProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //\"{0}\"
        pdfProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pdfProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pdfProcess.Start();
        pdfProcess.WaitForExit();
        pdfProcess.Close();
        //string output = pdfProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //string error = pdfProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("teste 1");
        //Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.WriteLine("teste 2");
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: Não é gerado nenhuma mensagem de erro simplesmente o arquivo não aparece no diretório e não ocorre nenhuma exceção.

Comment: conseguir resolver na linha de Arguments  adicionei o @ antes de digitar as aspas @"--headless --convert-to pdf --outdir C:\temp C:\temp\a.odt";

Answer (score 0):

conseguir resolverm na linha de Arguments adicionei o @ antes de digitar as aspas ficando assim

```
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"--headless --convert-to pdf --outdir C:\temp C:\temp\a.odt";
```